# arcgis python index of layer within a dataframe

Tags: python, arcgis

I am new to python and I have searched everywhere but I can not find an explicit method to get the index of a layer in the map, and more specifically in a given dataframe.
I have been able to list the layers using ListLayers function.

I have using this code which does not work, and i also did not really expect it to work, but I have tried other things and nothing, so I decided to ask the group, Thanks

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\PythonTest\Data\MyMap.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrarames(mxd, "MTM8")[0]
listlayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
for lyr in listlayer:
    print lyr.index(lyr)
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListLayers/00s30000002n000000/), `ListLayers` generates a list in the order in which the layers would appear in the ToC. What are you trying to do with this index value?

Answer (score 2):

The listlayers method returns a list of ArcGIS layer objects.  In your expression you are searching for the text name of the object and not the object itself.  This is why python will return ""lyr" is not in the list"

I'm also trying to work out the correct method for this.  What i have done thus far is to create two lists:

- a list of layer objects (Layerlist)
- a list of layer object names (retrievelist)

I can then pull out the layer object from layerlist by searching the text names in retrievelist retreiving the index and then slicing layerlist with that index position.  It seems "unclean" but since both list are in the exact same order it works.

I'd be interested in any cleaner solutions to this